# Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7

Tags: systemd, hibernate

Few days back, I ran `dmesg` on my terminal to see this line `Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7`

Sometimes, as in the image below [attached], the kernel ring buffer only prints this line repeatedly!

What is this diagnostic message regarding, and what does it mean? What should I be doing if it is something that I should dealing with immediately?

[image: dmesg]

Comment: Related: [Why does the kernel lockdown prevent hibernation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/591488/86440)

Answer (score 3):

I came across this topic while trying to figure out how to lift the kernel lockdown with secureboot enabled.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/591493

> The manpage gives false hope that encrypted hibernation would be supported in lockdown, but that’s currently not the case, and the real requirement appears to be signed hibernation images rather than (or presumably in addition to, depending on the lockdown mode) encrypted images.

With swap encryption enabled in ubuntu 18.04 on 5.3.0-70-generic and 5.4.0-65-generic, hibernation still does not work. After reading the twitter thread at the link provided, it seems to me that hibernate in secureboot is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried following advice in the error message and actually reading "man kernel_lockdown.7"?

Let me quote:

> Certain facilities are restricted... Unencrypted hibernation/suspend to swap are disallowed.

That's pretty much sums it up - enabling swap encryption should fix the problem.

Comment: If you can reasonably assume that the OP isn't trying to hibernate their system every 4 seconds, this answer is not very helpful.  I get the same message and I don't even have a swap partition.

Comment: In fact, on Ubuntu 20.04 there is no "kernel_lockdown.7" manpage.

Comment: @James [yes there is](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/kernel_lockdown.7.html), it just isn't included with some systems.

Comment: @NateT It's not. [Ubuntu Bug Tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1767971) is saying it's not available for 20.04 and trying to access it via [Ubuntu Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man7/kernel_lockdown.7.html) just boots back to 21.10, suggesting _it is not available_ as well :/

Answer (score 0):

1. This message shows up frequently in the logs, as soon as you boot your system (including a swap partition) with **Secure-Boot**. It warns you, that it will not hibernate unless you encrypt your swap-space in a way that the kernel recognizes.
2. If you do not need to hibernate, you can safely ignore this message. If you require hibernation, it depends on your distributions support how to enable encrypted disk or swap, which would require a varying amount of re-partitioning. However, the message will continue to show, even if encrypted hibernation becomes enabled. I am not aware of a way to disable this message other than patching the kernel.

This is from first hand experience with Secure-Boot + Hibernation on one particular distribution.

Comment: Is there a list of options to "encrypt your swap-space in a way that the kernel recognizes?" I'm considering using a swap file as my drive is already encrypted, but my boot environment is not, and I'm concerned that this will not be a recognized method.

Comment: You require a working Secure-Boot and at least encrypted swap. Succes is likely distribution-dependent.
cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747938/how-can-linux-hibernation-be-enabled-under-uefi-secure-boot-with-kernel-lockdown